# How to add static labels to plotly express `choropleth_mapbox`?

Tags: python, charts, plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

With current code I get hover tooltips, however those are not visible on PNG export. I need to have static label on each polygon.

[image: plotly choropleth_mapbox]

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=geojson, color="Bergeron",
                           locations="district", featureidkey="properties.district",
                           center={"lat": 45.5517, "lon": -73.7073},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", zoom=9)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Solutions which I found are not working, they work only for `choropleth` but not for `choropleth_mapbox` which I want to use. List of them:

https://community.plotly.com/t/labels-inside-counties-for-a-map/13953

https://community.plotly.com/t/annotations-on-plotly-choropleth/36219

https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-i-change-the-hover-labels-into-static-labels/4690/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the obvious answer is add a **Scattermapbox** layer with text that you want.  This is complicated by this [bug](https://community.plotly.com/t/scattermapbox-doesnt-work-with-marker-mode-as-text/35065). I did not find an clear replacement for **carto-positron** as a replacement on https://www.mapbox.com so the map style has changed
- create an account on https://account.mapbox.com to get a token, create a base map on https://studio.mapbox.com to create a base map
- also tried using [plotly annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/). However I could not find a way of getting bounding box of map to be able to transform lat/lot co-ords onto domain co-ords (0-1)

```
mapboxtoken="****"
mapboxstyle="mapbox://styles/***"
```

- use **geopandas** for simple access to `centroid` of geometries

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import geopandas as gpd

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()
gdf = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson)
    .merge(df, on="district")
    .assign(lat=lambda d: d.geometry.centroid.y, lon=lambda d: d.geometry.centroid.x)
    .set_index("district", drop=False)
)

# for convenience of rebuilding and adding traces...
def basemap():
    fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
        df,
        geojson=geojson,
        color="Bergeron",
        locations="district",
        featureidkey="properties.district",
        center={"lat": 45.5517, "lon": -73.7073},
        mapbox_style=mapboxstyle,
#         mapbox_style="carto-positron",
        zoom=9,
    )
    fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
                      mapbox={"accesstoken":mapboxtoken}
                     )
    return fig
```

#### pull it all together

```
texttrace = go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=gdf.geometry.centroid.y,
        lon=gdf.geometry.centroid.x,
        text=gdf["Bergeron"].astype(str),
        textfont={"color":"white","size":20, "family":"Courier New"},
        mode="text",
        name="Bergeron"
    )

basemap().add_trace(texttrace)
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Rob, really helpful. For anyone having trouble with this, please beware this only works for vector tiles which are: "basic", "streets", "outdoors", "light", "dark", "satellite", or "satellite-streets". Each of these styles require a mapbox key.